# Currency swap deals between countries

Tags: swaps, cross-currency-basis

Amidst bankruptcy situation in Sri-lanka, India is said to have come to rescue Sri-lanka, and entered into a currency swap deal as referenced here - https://www.cbsl.gov.lk/en/news/cbsl-enters-into-bilateral-currency-swap-agreement-with-rbi.

My question is, how exactly this type of deals help the donar country? With such kind of swap, it is actually receiving the weak currency of the bankrupt country, right? Or, it is just some kind of charity?

Comment: Don't know the details but presumably they have agreed that the foreign currency is paid back with some interest.

Comment: Yes, it is essentially an emergency loan. Sri Lanka will use the USD it borrows to buy goods (imports) from abroad. *Some of those goods may well come from India, Sri Lanka's neighbor.* So Indian business potentially benefit indirectly.